How to Custom Navbar component in Bulma framework?
I want to full width of <router link> element in navbar component. How can I achieve that. I also interested in some keywords about something like this.
Here is my error:

I want a full-width layout like this, regardless of the size of the Chrome window.

I'm new in Bulma, I tried to read anything that I can find out in the NavBar Bulma official documents, It's hard for me to custom this framework.
NavBar.vue
......
  <nav
    class="navbar is-info is-fixed-top"
    role="navigation"
    aria-label="main navigation"
  >
    <div class="container is-max-desktop px-4">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <div class="navbar-item is-size-4 is-family-monospace">Noteballs</div>

        <a
          @click="showMobileNav = !showMobileNav"
          role="button"
          class="navbar-burger"
          :class="{ 'is-active': showMobileNav }"
          aria-label="menu"
          aria-expanded="false"
          data-target="navbarBasicExample"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div
        id="navbarBasicExample"
        class="navbar-menu"
        :class="{ 'is-active': showMobileNav }"
      >
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <router-link to="/" class="navbar-item" active-class="is-active"
            >Notes</router-link
          >
          <router-link to="/stats" class="navbar-item" active-class="is-active"
            >Stats</router-link
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
.....

ViewNotes.vue
<template>
  <div class="notes">
    <div class="has-background-success-dark p-4 mb-5">
      <div class="field">
        <!-- <label class="label">Message</label> -->
        <div class="control">
          <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Add a new note"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-grouped is-grouped-right">
        <div class="control">
          <button class="button is-link has-background-success">Add New Note</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-for="i in 3" class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium
          adipisci, odit saepe sequi rem animi odio? Vitae sequi ea dolorum
          laboriosam a, quos, amet animi, esse id nobis vel ad.
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


What error do you have exactly? A bit confused since we're talking about CSS here. Also, what do you want full-width? notes and stats? Have you inspected the elements in your devtools?

I want to full width of notes and stats component.

Really not sure what you mean by that. Mind providing a drawing or something? You cannot achieve that by using CSS and inspecting the elements in your devtools?

I updated my expectation for detail

So you don't want the burger button but only the text? Hm, how do you think it will work on a mobile with 300px width? Users will not be able to access the website on mobile.

Do you need help with anything else?

Bulma is probably not the framework you're looking for here, for this specific reason.
Vertical by default

Every element in Bulma is mobile-first and optimizes for vertical reading, so by default on mobile:
...
the nav menu will be hidden

At the same time, all good UI libraries are mobile-first. So if you don't want such behavior, you should probably override it but then what's the point of using a thing that will not behave as you want anyway?
I still think that you should think about mobile users tho, because people might have smaller devices than you in general.
I also have not found any way to change the default breakpoints, unfortunately.
Maybe give a try to TailwindCSS or UI libraries based on it, so that you maybe have more flexibility regarding the breakpoints that you'd like to change to your liking (if you want to break popular UX rules).

Thank you your enthusiasm.  Honestly, I'm not strong about CSS, I try .notes {width: 100%}, but It's not work as I expect.

I don't have any ideal for fixing that.

@happy You have a lot of things to CSS so it's usually not a simple fix. I recommend starting slow, then trying Tailwind, and then maybe some UI libraries. It's important to have nice foundations before using abstractions like Bulma. Because in case you struggle with CSS, dealing with Bulma will be even more difficult. To the point where doing your own thing might be easier.

Yes, thank you for your recommendation. I'm learning a course Udemy. However, it's old version of Bulma. Of course, in the video, there are no errors like mine. Maybe, after finishing the course, I will try Tailwind.

@happy take some time to properly learn CSS before trying Tailwind. Like, make 1 or 2 projects with just CSS and nothing else. Things on top of it are nice to move faster but they do not help that much if you do not master them without the abstraction. Consider some official and up-to-date resources too: https://web.dev/learn/css

I did, this is some demo projects that I have completed. https://merry-granita-2b4014.netlify.app/ , https://nimble-fox-1f3e8f.netlify.app/ . Github: https://github.com/manhcntt21/html-css-projects

Nice, reminds me of that one: https://www.frontendmentor.io/
